# Does the "Middle School Mathematics domains" refer to (I) through (V) topics?

Tags: terminology, middle-school

Does the "**Middle School Mathematics domains**" on page 3 of https://www.ets.org/content/dam/ets-org/pdfs/praxis/5164.pdf refer to the the following 5 topics/categories?

> (I) Numbers and Operations, (II) Algebra, (III) Functions, (IV) Geometry and Measurement, and (V) Statistics and Probability

[image]

Comment: Why do you ask this? You can just read the document, can't you? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Dominique The screenshot is from the document. OP is asking if the phrase "Middle School Mathematics domains" beneath the table is referring to the "Content Categories" column in the table.

Comment: A country tag on the question would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It says

> all questions assess content from the **above** Middle School Mathematics domains,

and the only thing directly **above** is the table. And the only text fields in the table are the content categories:

> (I) Numbers and Operations
>
> (II) Algebra
>
> (III) Functions
>
> (IV) Geometry and Measurement
>
> (V) Statistics and Probability

So, the phrase "Middle School Mathematics domains" refers to the "Content Categories" column in the table.